# A question I answered was closed as a duplicate - should I answer the linked question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, allowed-answers

I answered [question A](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250799/do-i-need-to-perform-my-next-hack-within-24-hours-of-the-current-one-in-order-to), which was later closed as a duplicate of [question B](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210104/what-is-the-logic-behind-the-timer-of-the-sojourner-badge). I feel that the answer I wrote on question A provides more information or is more correct than the current, existing answers on question B.

Would there be something wrong with copying my answer on question A to question B?

Comment: Kind of a grey area I would say... Unless the question that was closed as a duplicate gets deleted, I would say do not answer question B.

Comment: I could see changing the order of duplicate. The new question is pretty clear and well written, and has an updated answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if you think your answer is better than existing answers, post it! We want the *best* answers we can get.

See: [Duplicate answers and you](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12448/duplicate-answers-and-you)

Comment: I've added my answer to question B. Thank you for the input.