# Do answers get pushed into Low Quality Posts when they gather enough downvotes?

Tags: support, voting, reviewing

Part of [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12448) says:

> Is it incorrect? Downvote it (and **if it gets enough downvotes, it’ll get kicked into the low quality queue where the community can delete it**).

Emphasis mine. Is this true? Are downvotes really enough to send an answer to Low Quality Posts review?

Note: I think this may be site-specific, so I'm asking on Meta Arqade instead of Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181798/310045