# What's wrong with my answer?

Tags: discussion, allowed-answers

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322605/201215

I didn't expect it to be downvoted, but more, I didn't expect it to garner *a delete vote.*

I'm new around here, so I haven't grasped the culture. I wonder if the community here frowns upon answering a question that has accepted answer?

Or is there anything else wrong with my answer? Too short? Did I somehow missed the question? Anything to improve?

Comment: No source — please add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if a question already has an answer (regardless of acceptance), any new answers need to bring something new that wasn't mentioned in a current answer. This can be something the answer has missed, something that contradicts the existing answer but has merit, a deeper analysis of aspects of the previous answer, or something which interprets the question in a new light and provides a solution to a prerequisite problem in the original question. In addition, we prefer answers which are less susceptible to changes, AND answers with a credible and accurate source.

In your case, you bring new information, namely hard numbers. However, hard numbers like these tend to be really volatile. If Valve decides to change the base EXP that creeps reward, but not the percentage that denying grants, your answer becomes outdated. The accepted answer doesn't become outdated if the base EXP changes. Both your answers become outdated if the percentages change.

your answer also does not have a source for the EXP values. The accepted answer doesn't provide a source either, but it appears to come straight from the path 7.07 patch notes. That makes it more credible.

Comment: Hi, I'm the one who cast the delete vote. I came to this question to write an answer, but then I found yours which perfectly mirrors my reasoning for it. So I'm just letting everyone know that this is correct.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/how-do-we-handle-duplicate-answers?rq=1), the community seems to be in favor of deleting answers that have the same information as the accepted one. That's why your answer was given a delete vote.

The only thing that I would recommend is try to source your answers where possible. We really like sourced answers in order to validate the answer.

Seeing as how you are new here, I would also like to say that your answer is already way ahead of most new users. Don't let edits, downvotes or delete votes be taken personally, keep up the detailed answers and welcome!